# htaccess rewrite exclusion not working on directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been stuck on this problem for hours and cannot find a suitable solution. I am running an ecommerce CMS from a directory eg. mywebsite.com/store/

/ has an .htaccess file which doesn't seem to change anything in /store/
/store/ has its own .htaccess file which i have been adding changes too

I have been trying to restrict access to the admin panel using the following rule to only 2 IP addresses.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/?(index.php/)?admin123/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^185.66.7.254$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^217.41.62.40$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

However the major problem is that this redirects all users going to any URL not containing /admin123/ to /, otherwise it works as expected in restricting admin panel. How do I fix this?

UPDATE 08/02: As of yet I still have not found a workable solution to this issue, at best I can blacklist ISP IPs to the whole /store/ folder using "deny from"

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the base path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /store/
```

Comment: Sorry I should mention it is already contained within RewriteEngine On. And adding RewriteBase /store/ changed nothing